# Get Visible rectangle of UIView added as a subview

Tags: iphone, ios

[image]

As show in Picture above UIView A & UIView C are Added on UIView B. for B ClipToBounds is YES so the Red area is not visible.

Is it possible to get Visible rectangle of A & C ( shown with Lines )

I need show Rectangle in visible area when I touches e.g View A. thats it.

[image]

Comment: what you want exactly?? you want to capture that view as a Image??

Comment: No, Just need to get visible rectangle of View A & View B.

Comment: have updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can get an intersection rect of the two rects by using [CGRectIntersection()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH1g-F17157) method

```
CGRect intersectionRect = CGRectIntersection(viewA.frame, viewB.frame);
if(CGRectIsNull(intersectionRect)) {
   //Rects do not intersect
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can with this function:

```
CGRect CGRectIntersection (
   CGRect r1,
   CGRect r2
);
```

If you tell exactly what you want to do maybe are better ways, for example i needed something similar and instead cropping manually i just captured the UIView B content as an image.

Comment: I suppose you can keep view A to alpha 0 if you use the touch event on it. If you use the event on B you can check if you touched A with CGRectContainsPoint and use the hidden property to show or hide A.

Answer (score 0):

Use for this

```
[UIView convertRect:<#(CGRect)#> fromView:<#(UIView *)#>]
[UIView convertRect:<#(CGRect)#> toView:<#(UIView *)#>]
```

And CGRectIntersection function

Answer (score 0):

on `touchesEnded:` method you can find it like bellow..

```
  -(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *) touches {
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect([ViewA frame], [ViewB frame]) {
      //Do something here
    }
  }
```

Read More Information about RectInterSect From [This Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint)

i hope its helpful to you...

Comment: @sagar... see this link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint may be you find something which is useful for you... :)