# Getting Visible Rect of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit, cgrect

What's the simplest method to get the visible rect of any arbitrary `UIView` as a `CGRect`, assuming that the `UIView` is only clipped along the edges (no other views breaking it up somewhere in the middle)?

For clarity, this method should not only retrieve the visible rect relative to the view's superview. But relative to all it's ancestors at a minimum and ideally relative to all siblings as well.

Comment: The closest I have come to is walking the view tree backwards from view to superview and checking for intersecting rects. However, I'm running into issues with `UITableViewCell`s having odd frame origins (may have something to do with the content offset). Also, this doesn't account for siblings that may cover the view. Wondering if anyone has already solved this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a UIView's visible rectangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373112/getting-a-uiviews-visible-rectangle)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Visible rectangle of UIView added as a subview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696760/get-visible-rectangle-of-uiview-added-as-a-subview)

Comment: Aaron Brager - Did you even read the comment I wrote?

Comment: @Awesome-o did you find a solution?

Comment: I ended up having to delegate back through the layers of view controllers and do the math at each level. I couldn't find a truly general solution but it solved my use cases. I'm sure there's still some better solution to this though.

Comment: @Awesome-o That's exactly what I'm doing at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Try this!

```
CGRect visibleRect = CGRectIntersection(self.frame, superview.bounds);
```

Comment: Doesn't cover every case expressed in the question.