# Is there a 'getGlobalVisibleRect' equivalent on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, avplayer

Is there an equivalent of [getGlobalVisibleRect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getGlobalVisibleRect%28android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Point%29) in `Objective-C` ? I'm trying to get the visible rect of a subview that could be obscured by other views above it in the parent view hierarchy but it seems very tedious as some other similar [question(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311554/getting-visible-rect-of-uiview) on SO indicate. The desired implementation is to auto play some content in an `AVPlayer` view if a certain percentage of the `AVPlayer` view is visible on screen, similar to how `Facebook` auto-plays video media in one's feed. However this seems convoluted with having to firstly get the root view and recursively check with its subviews and their subviews and their subviews... and do a `CGRectIntersectsRect` with the player view & every subview above it. Surely there's got to be a simpler way to do this or am I headed down the path of recursion?